# Shopify data from the store search bar

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

Is there any way that when the user enters and searches for example "long white wedding dress" I can intercept or capture or access this data with possible search terms?

I need it for statistics of searched products and how efficiently a product is reached in the webshop

Thank you very much!